# Prism Unsubscribe with subscription token not working

Tags: c#, .net, prism

I am subscribing and unsubscribing to prism events using the code below in ClassA. The problem I am having is **after** I unsubscribe, and another completely different class, say ClassB, with a different handler registers for the same event, ClassA handler is still invoked. Why is this?

I have tried both unsubscribing using a token as well as the method delegate used when registering, both to no avail.

```
SubscriptionToken _subscriptionToken;

//register subscription + handler
var pevent = GetEventAggregator().GetEvent<PriceSubscriptionEvent>();
_subscriptionToken = pevent.Subscribe(r =>
{
    DataHandler(r);
    return;
}, ThreadOption.BackgroundThread, false, null);

//Unsubscribe
var pevent = GetEventAggregator().GetEvent<PriceSubscriptionEvent>();
pevent.Unsubscribe(_subscriptionToken);
```

Comment: Man, I had this same problem and eventually solved it ... but that was over a year ago and now I can't remember what the fix or work-around was. :\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310663/wpf-prism-event-subcriptions-not-dying

Comment: SubscriptionToken also implementes IDisposable. Do you tried to invoke Dispose instead of calling Unsubscribe on EventAggregator?

Comment: FYI: We don't do "pings" here, please refrain from doing so in the future.

Comment: Try this link: http://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com/2009/05/prism-event-aggregator-subscription.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the Unsubscribe can work there since you used an anonymous method on your Subscribe call. Try moving the code for subscribe in a separate method and the subscribe / unsubscribe to / from it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about subscriptiontoken code here.

But, we can subscribe and unsubscribe the event as follows:

```
evenaggregator.GetEvent<EventName>().Subscribe(eventhandler);
```

and

```
evenaggregator.GetEvent<EventName>().Unsubscribe(eventhandler);
```

It works for me.